# Update a set of panels when a variable changes

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a group of panels( three for now ) which are all the instances of the same view.
So they have a lot things in common,like toolbar and the buttons on them.

I define toolbars' and buttons' text when i create them and the text comes from a variable, like this:

```
App.views.CommonView = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
  initComponent: function() {

    this.backBtn = new Ext.Button({
      text: globalVar,
      handler: this.onBackTap,
      scope: this
    });

    this.toolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
      title: this.title,
      items: [this.backBtn]
    });
   }
});

anInstanceView: new App.views.CommonView({
    title: globalVar
});

anotherInstanceView: new App.views.CommonView({
    title: globalVar
});
```

As you can see, the button text and the toolbar title relies on the globalVar.

I want to update those texts all together when i change this golbalVar's value

```
globalVar = "new value";
// Somehow update all the button and toolbar texts on all three panels.
```

I don't want to do this manually like;

```
App.views.anInstanceView.getDockedItems[0].setTitle(globalVar);
```

and repeat it for all the panels. There needs to be a cleaner solution, a method to update the ui.

What could be that cleaner solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a method in your common view which does all the updates for you based on the globalVar's value. You can then call this method for each instance after you update the globalVar or create a global Message Bus with an 'globalvarupdate' event which each instance could listen for and then update itself. Something along the lines of...

```
// somewhere in your app setup
App.messageBus = new Ext.util.Observable();
App.messageBus.addEvents('globalvarupdate');
```

.

```
App.views.CommonView = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
  initComponent: function() {

    this.backBtn = new Ext.Button({
      text: globalVar,
      handler: this.onBackTap,
      scope: this
    });

    this.toolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
      title: this.title,
      items: [this.backBtn]
    });

      // listen for globalvarupdate on the message bus and do the titles update
      App.messageBus.on('globalvarupdate', this.updateTitles, this);
   },

   updateTitles: function(){
      // do all updates here
   }
});
```

.

```
// when you need to update globalvar
globalvar = 'My New Title';
App.messageBus.fireEvent('globalvarupdate');
```

That code is totally untested but hopefully gives you an idea for a possible approach.

Comment: this is a very good solution to my problem. helped a lot, thanks.